# Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$

(i) If A is connected, is $f^ {−1} (A)$ so?

(ii) If A is compact, is $f^{−1} (A)$ so?

(iii) If A is finite, is $f^ {−1} (A)$ so?

(iv) If A is bounded, is $f^ {−1} (A)$ so?

No, consider $f(x)=(x-1)(x-2), f^{-1}(0)=\{1,2\}$, the rest of three can be countered by constant function right?

Comment: It seems correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your suggested counterexamples are correct.  While continuous functions must map connected sets to connected sets, compact sets to compact sets, and finite sets to finite sets, and uniformly continuous functions must map bounded sets to bounded sets, the same does not hold for preimage.

Comment: yippeeeeeeeeeee

Comment: Just a note: what does hold is that the preimage of open sets is open; this is the topological definition of continuity.